# Slow performance after syncing storage bucket with gcsfuse

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, gcsfuse

I've run into a bug that seemingly has no explanation as to why its happening.

Running scripts that are in my mounted drive(mounted using gcsfuse) takes forever to run(almost a couple of minutes per command). However, any scripts that I run from outside the mount folder seems to work fine. I can also notice a significant lag in the cursor movement too. Using GCS is a must for me as my dataset is already uploaded there and trying to rsync it to the VM takes forever.

I would appreciate any help regarding this issue.

Here is the cloud monitoring dashboard for some metrics I measured.
[image: https://imgur.com/a/kIcJhFb]
[image]